# How to sum the value of 2 different SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm kinda new to using SQL. I have two different queries and I need to add or sum the value of one of the column in each queries. Sample code and screenshot of the outcome are provided below:

```
WITH tbl AS 
(   
    SELECT 
        y.Location, 
        IIF(Status = 'Completed', 1,0) as Completed,  
        IIF(Status = 'Pending', 1, 0) as Pending,
        IIF(Status = 'Scheduled', 1, 0) as Scheduled,
        IIF(Satisfied = 'Satisfied', 1 , 0 ) As Satisfied, 
        IIF(Attrition IN ('Red', 'Amber'),1,0) As Attrition
    FROM
        order x
    LEFT JOIN 
        roster y ON x.customerID = y.cID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_calendar z ON (x.starttime between z.datestart AND z.dateend)
    WHERE 
        y.LOCATION IS NOT NULL 
        AND y.Location <> 'Ireland' 
        AND z.month ='2' 
        AND z.week IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.split('1,2,3',','))
        AND z.year = '2017'
)
SELECT 
    Location, 
    SUM(Completed) AS Completed, 
    SUM(Pending) AS Pending, 
    SUM(Scheduled) AS Scheduled, 
    SUM(Satisfied) as Satisfied, 
    SUM(Attrition) as Attrition  
FROM
    tbl 
GROUP BY 
    Location
```

[image]

And here is the second query:

```
SELECT 
    y.location, count (*) as qc 
FROM 
    customer_quality x
LEFT JOIN 
    roster y ON x.customerEID = y.cEID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_calendar z ON (x.DateTimeDelivered BETWEEN z.datestart AND z.dateend)
WHERE 
    y.location IS NOT NULL
    AND x.status = '4' 
    AND z.month = '2' 
    AND z.week IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.split('1,2,3',',')) 
    AND z.year = '2017'
GROUP BY
    y.Location
```

[image]

What I'm going to need to do is to add the value of the total completed orders from query 1 to the total quality customer on my query 2.

For example:

If there are 208 completed customer in Lisbon it would up the other 4 quality customer, the total should be  212.

It would show like this:

```
Location    Completed   Pending     Scheduled   Satisfied   Attrition
Kuala Lumpur    388      76           9            388         3
Lisbon          212      92          29            207         1
Manila         3535      97         167            662        24
Mumbai          538      50          54            2100        6
Warsaw          147      38           4            145         9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have data to test, but this should get you started.

```
With tbl  as 
(   SELECT y.Location, 
             IIF(Status = 'Completed', 1,0) as Completed,  
             IIF(Status = 'Pending', 1, 0) as Pending,
             IIF(Status = 'Scheduled', 1, 0) as Scheduled,
             IIF(Satisfied = 'Satisfied', 1 , 0 ) As Satisfied, 
             IIF(Attrition IN ('Red', 'Amber'),1,0) As Attrition
    FROM order x
         LEFT JOIN roster y ON x.customerID=y.cID 
         LEFT JOIN tbl_calendar z ON (x.starttime between z.datestart AND z.dateend)
    WHERE y.LOCATION IS NOT NULL 
             AND y.Location <> 'Ireland' 
             AND z.month ='2' 
             AND z.week IN (select * from dbo.split('1,2,3',','))
             AND z.year='2017'
)

SELECT Location, 
       SUM(Completed) AS Completed , 
       SUM (Pending) AS Pending, 
       SUM(Scheduled) AS Scheduled, 
       SUM(Satisfied) as Satisfied, 
       SUM(Attrition) as Attrition 
INTO #TABLE1 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Location

SELECT y.location, count (*) as qc 
INTO #TABLE2
FROM customer_quality x
     LEFT JOIN roster y ON x.customerEID = y.cEID
     LEFT JOIN tbl_calendar z ON (x.DateTimeDelivered between z.datestart 
AND z.dateend)
WHERE y.location is not null 
      AND x.status='4' AND z.month = '2' 
      AND z.week IN (select * FROM dbo.split('1,2,3',',')) AND z.year='2017'
GROUP by y.Location



SELECT t1.Location
        , (t1.Completed + t2.qc) AS Completed
        , t1.Pending
        , t1.Scheduled
        , t1.Satisfied
        , t1.Attrition
FROM #TABLE1 t1
    JOIN #TABLE2 t2 ON
        t1.Location = t2.Location



DROP TABLE #TABLE1
DROP TABLE #TABLE2
```

Comment: hi maderson, I tried this code. though it worked. when there's no data in qc for a location, let's say kuala lumpur, it won't show in the table

Comment: Then you'll have to play with the #TABLE1 to #TABLE2 join. Will all the locations always be in #TABLE2? If so, select from that first, then join #TABLE1. If both tables can have different locations, then you'll have to use another join. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-join-types

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 CTEs as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx#C-Using-multiple-CTE-definitions-in-a-single-query and then join them together and perform the desired calculations in your *SELECT* final clause

Answer (score 0):

Or you could store you results from the first query in a temporary table using

```
SELECT * INTO #temp1 FROM (
    SELECT Location, 
       SUM(Completed) AS Completed , 
       SUM (Pending) AS Pending, 
       SUM(Scheduled) AS Scheduled, 
       SUM(Satisfied) as Satisfied, 
       SUM(Attrition) as Attrition  
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY Location
)
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO #temp2 FROM (
    SELECT y.location, count (*) as qc 
    FROM customer_quality x
         LEFT JOIN roster y ON x.customerEID = y.cEID
         LEFT JOIN tbl_calendar z ON (x.DateTimeDelivered between z.datestart AND z.dateend)
    WHERE y.location is not null 
          AND x.status='4' AND z.month = '2' 
          AND z.week IN (select * FROM dbo.split('1,2,3',',')) AND z.year='2017'
    GROUP by y.Location
)
```

in the end the summarizing query could be:

```
SELECT t1.location
, t1.COMPLETED + t2.cq AS Completed
, t1.Pending
, t1.Scheduled
, t1.Satisfied
, t1.Attrition
FROM #temp1 t1
JOIN #temp2 t2 on t1.location = t2.location
```

or take the approach of stringing the CTEs together.